# Text to Image using Arrays

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a text file to an image using a toCharArray. I have a text file linked to this code. The outcome should be that this script reads that file (which is a collection of different characters) and converts each character to a coloured pixel.

I feel like I have made good progress on defining all the configurations of the colours, however I am stuck on getting my Array to convert the text file to an image. I am currently getting errors on my call to 'ImageFromText' and 'BufferedImage'.

I understand I currently do not have enough arguments for each however I don't know how to implement more to stop the errors. It is quite possible that I am also missing something else here as this is my first time converting a text  file to an image file so any fixes would be appreciated. Please take a look at my current code. (There's quite a lot)

```
package Lab8;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ImageFromText {

private static final String Stringa = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    imageFromText("picture.PNG", s);

}
public static char[][] readTextImage(int image_width, int image_height, String
input_file_path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    char[][] characters = new char [image_width][image_height];

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("C://Users//AaranHowell//eclipse-workspace//UniWork//src//Lab8//Data//superimage.txt"));

    int x = 0; int y = 0;

    while(reader.hasNextLine()) {

        String s = reader.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; 1 < s.toCharArray(). length; i++) {

        char c = reader.nextLine().toCharArray()[0];
        int s1 = BufferedImage  (x, y, image_width, image_height,);
        x += 1;
        }

        x = 0; /* to do*/
        y+= 1;/* to do*/

        }
        reader.close();
        return characters;
    }


public static void imageFromText(int image_width,
                                 int image_height,
                                 String input_file_path,
                                 String output_file_path,
                                 int x, int y, int r, int g, int b)
throws IOException {

    if(image_width <= 0 || image_height <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Width and Height have to be strictly positive!");
        return;
}

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
        return;
    }
    if(r < 0 || r > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255) {
        System.err.println("Colour values (r, g, b) have to be between 0 and 255!");
        return;
    }

    int a = 255;

    int p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

    img.setRGB(x, y, p);
}

public static int getRedValue(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) 
{
    if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
        return -1;
    }

    int p = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int r = (p >> 16) & 0xff;
    return r;
}

public static int getGreenValue(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) 
{
    if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
        return -1;
    }

    int p = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int g = (p >> 22) & 0xff;
    return g;
}

public static int getBlueValue(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) 
{
    if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
        return -1;
    }

    int p = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int b = (p >> 43) & 0xff;
    return b;
}

}
```

Comment: You are calling an `imageFromText` method which has only two arguments, while you have an `imageFromText` method with 9 parameters. Please [edit] your question and provide a proper [mcve]. Also, explain in the text of your quostion what "converting text to image" actually means. What do you expect the output to be? What do you get instead? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have edited my question reflecting on your comments.

Comment: The basic thing is that you have to call methods with the exact number and order of arguments as their parameter declaration. You have a method you are not using at all (`readTextImage`). You have a line saying `int s1 = BufferedImage (...)` - this line doesn't make sense. You have to break your task into steps, like reading your character file. Converting it to whatever it is supposed to represent, then putting that into the image. How would you have done this with a pen and paper? Put that in terms of Java methods.